# Joining tables during insert to get a unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to populate a table (`Loc`) with data from another table (`Test.dbo.ML`).

The `[VALID_FROM]` field should be populated with a date from a third table (`Test.dbo.TEN`), which has to be joined to a fourth table (`Test.dbo.ST`) to determine which `N_ID` should be used to get the date. And this is the problem I am having!

The `[N_ID]` field which is immediately after the `SELECT` statement must be the `s.N_ID` in the `where` clause of the join. How can I do something like that?

I am using SQL Server 2017.

I Looked into `@@IDENTITY` AND `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but these seem to be unrelated to the problem I am trying to solve.

```
INSERT INTO [Loc] ([LOC_ID], [TYPE], [ADRESS], [POST_CODE], 
                   [LAT], [LONG], [GEOMETRY], [VALID_FROM])
    SELECT
        [N_ID], 'some place', [ADDRESS], [FSALDU],
        [COORDY], [COORDX], [GEOM],
        (SELECT MIN(t.open_date) 
         FROM Test.dbo.TEN t
         JOIN Test.dbo.ST s ON t.S_ID = s.S_ID
         WHERE s.N_ID = 'problem is here!')
    FROM
        Test.dbo.ML
```

For the `[VALID_FROM]` field I have to get the earliest available date, and hence `MIN(t.open_date)`.

Test.dbo.TEN (S_ID, open_date)

Test.dbo.ST (S_ID, N_ID)

Test.dbo.ML (N_ID, ADDRESS, FSALDU, COORDY, COORDX, GEOM)

This is an insert statement but getting the earliest open_date for the right N_ID that is being inserted into the new table [Loc] is the real issue here!

Comment: So the N_ID you want is the one with the earliest open date?   Not really clear what you are try to accomplish.    I suspect you want a group by and TOP 1, but need more information

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result from that data.

Comment: Am I missing something? Can't you just do `SELECT
  m.[N_ID]
  ,'some place'
  ,[ADDRESS]
  ,[FSALDU]
  ,[COORDY]
  ,[COORDX]
  ,[GEOM]
  ,MIN(t.open_date) 
from Test.dbo.ML m    
      join Test.dbo.ST on s.N_ID = m.n_ID Join Test.dbo.TEN t on t.S_ID = s.S_ID` You didn't really explain the schema and relationships properly, or give any sample data or expected result so it's hard to be sure. But that's just my suggestion

Comment: Aside: Now is a good time to forget about `@@Identity`. `Scope_Identity()` is useful for single rows and the [`output clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) works with multiple rows and, for `update` statements, provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @ADyson I used your suggestion, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I should add the geometry column cannot be in the group by clause as I get error with the geometry type column... Msg 249, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
The type "geometry" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause. But the suggestion works for all the rest of the columns - GEOMETRY\GEOM.

Comment: You have not used a group by clause in your example so I'm not sure what you are talking about with that. But glad the rest of it was useful. I added it as a proper answer for you

Comment: At first I did not think to use insert statement I would need to use Group By clause as well. But I suppose when I joined tables I really had to use a Group By clause and specify all non-aggregate columns in that clause. I did insert Geometry data type before with insert/select statements without any aggregate columns though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; it reminded me of another venue to try...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a subquery here...you can just join all the tables directly:

```
select m.[N_ID] ,'some place' ,[ADDRESS] ,[FSALDU] ,[COORDY] ,[COORDX] ,[GEOM] ,MIN(t.open_date) 
from Test.dbo.ML m 
  join Test.dbo.ST on s.N_ID = m.n_ID 
  join Test.dbo.TEN t on t.S_ID = s.S_ID
```

Comment: I think you are missing a Group By clause here! Group By is to be used when you are using aggregate columns.

Comment: I am using the exact same code I placed in the comments above, and which you commented to say "it worked, thank you". You didn't have a group by and you didn't ask for one . It's not obligatory to use a group by with an aggregate. It depends what result you want. So did this code work for you, or not? Now I'm not clear...

Comment: Your suggestion in above comments helped me to re-formulate my thoughts... and I made my comment based on that. I have commented above that I did not expect to use group by clause, however the suggested solution did work only after I used the Group By clause, and removed the geometry type data from the insert query. Sorry this wasn't clear in previous comments I made.

Comment: Ok I understand better now. The best thing might be to post your own answer to the question then, with the final version of the code. You are allowed to answer your own question